# Javascript - заполнение пунктов списка <select>

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Являясь новичком в программировании столкнулся с задачей: есть функция, которая генерирует случайное число от 0 до 100 `var val = Math.round(Math.random()*(100 - 0)) + 0;`. Необходимо вывести значение функции как один из пунктов списка `<select>`. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: а по какому событию срабатывает функция?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем виде можно так:

```js
let val = Math.round(Math.random()*(100 - 0)) + 0;
document.getElementById('random').textContent = val;
```

```html
<select>
<option>выберите пункт</option>
<option>ABC</option>
<option>DEF</option>
<option id="random"></option>
<option>GHI</option>
<option>GKL</option>
</select>
```

То есть сейчас функция отрабатывает при загрузке страницы и выводит значение в option.

Comment: Поменяется ли суть, если от этого случайного значения я захочу отнять (или прибавить) какое то число и так же вывести его в option?

Comment: @Sam324, в option выводится конечное значение переменной val. Совершенно неважно, какие вычисления производятся до этого.